# Vertical centring in table

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularx

I was wondering how to fix the following problem with table formatting: I am trying to get the text to be vertically centred in each cell, but, as you can see from this photo, there appears to be a smaller gap above the 'Title' and below it. Can anyone suggest a way of making the title sit right in the middle of the two horizontal lines?
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
 \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{11pt}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
    \toprule
\multirow{1}{*}[0pt]{Title}
       &   \multirow{1}{*}[0pt]{Title}
            &   \multirow{1}{*}[0pt]{Title}            
                 &   \multirow{1}{*}[0pt]{Title}  \\
    \midrule
    Something & something & something & something
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, if your cells letters have descenders, the contents is vertically centred.

Comment: I'd like it to be centred even without them

Comment: Since you load `makecell`, the simplest would be to use `\Gape[2.7pt][0pt]{Title} ` for one of the cells in the first row. Of course the values in the optional argument might have to be adjusted depending on the real contents of this first row.